# c# mysql data validation against SQL Injection

Tags: c#, mysql

I want to know if there are any commands that you can use in C# that can protect against SQL Injection.

I have a program that is connected to my database, I want to ensure that they cannot enter any malicious code through a text box or other means.

```
 string Query = "Update users SET Calories = @Calories WHERE username = '" + txtName.Text + "' AND Day = '" + cboDayofWeek.Text + "'";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, Conn);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Calories", txtCalories.Text);
```

Comment: You're parameterising `@Calories`.  Why not do the same with your other literals?

Comment: I see, and does parameterising invalidate any attempt of malicious code?

Comment: Short of there being exploitable bugs in the implementation, it will prevent all forms of SQL injection.